# How to pass class name as parameter and then using it to check if an object is an instance of that class in java?

Tags: java

I read few stack overflow responses of questions similar to this but could not get satisfying answer. I want to create a generic method which accepts a graph object of type E. I want to pass this object alongwith a class name. In that method, I want to read an input from user and check if that is an instance of given class and throw some error message if it is not. I tried to use following code for the same:

```
public void readDependencyPair(Scanner scanner, String prompt, MyGraph<E> graph, String clazz) {
        System.out.println(prompt);
        Object obj = scanner.next();
        Class<?> c = Class.forName(clazz);
        if(obj instanceof c) {...
        }
}
```

The above code gives error at line "if obj is instance of c" saying "c cannot be resolved to a type. Create class 'c' or interface 'c' or enum 'c'".

I even tried to pass Class clazz instead of String parameter. And it still shows the same error that 'clazz' cannot be resolved to a type.

Comment: You can't say `obj instanceof c` - you would need an actual class, but there's no point because `obj` is a `String` so unless you input `java.lang.String` - this wouldn't work.

Comment: I see. So is there no other way where I can achieve this ?

Comment: What about comparing `obj.getClass().getName()` with `clazz`

Comment: You can check it by `if (obj.getClass() == c)`, but it seems there is no relationship between `obj` and `c`.

Comment: What does the graph or its generic type `E` have to do with any of this?

Comment: @ElijahSeedArita As commented by Elliot Frisch, obj.getClass() will always return String, so there is no relationship between obj and c.

Comment: @KevinJ.Chase I want to check if obj is instance of provided class and if it is, store it in that graph.

Comment: If you're resigned to storing both the collection and its type-as-a-`String`, why not store the collection and its type-as-a-`Class<?>` instead?  You'll have to convert the `String` back to a `Class` to do anything useful, anyway.  (You can't use `E` itself as a type, due to type erasure.  And you can't use the `.class` of an item from the collection, because the collection might be empty, and because the object might be too narrow --- say a `Double` in a collection of `Number`.)

Comment: @AnujaP What I'm saying is that you can compare the getClass string with the string in the function name. But I tested this out and it seems to return the whole package location so sub-optimal

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
if (c.isInstance(obj))
    ....
```

see the [docs here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance-java.lang.Object-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use  Class for parameter type, for example, to declare a function like:

```
public boolean isInstance(Class<?> c,Object obj){
        return obj.getClass().equals( c);
    }
```

Then use it in this way:

```
@Test
public void testIsInstance(){
    User u = new User();
    Assert.assertTrue(isInstance( User.class, u));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's already an existing method for what you're trying to do, `Class#isAssignableFrom`:

```
public void readDependencyPair(Scanner scanner, String prompt, MyGraph<E> graph, String clazz) {
    System.out.println(prompt);
    String obj = scanner.next();
    Class<?> c = Class.forName(clazz);

    if(Class.forName(obj).isAssignableFrom(c)) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree that `isAssignableFrom` is the right method to use.  But this still has the problem that `obj` will always be a `String`, because [`Scanner.next`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next--) can't returns anything else.  You'll need to replace `Object obj` with something like `String userClassName = scanner.next();` followed by `Class<?> userClass = Class.forName(userClassName)`.

Comment: @KevinJ.Chase Of course; I was just using OP's example.